# Forms not submitting inside Bootstrap modal with Turbolinks turned on Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-4, turbolinks, bootstrap-modal

I've made forms to be submitted in modals provided by Bootstrap 3.0.
However the forms only submit when I refresh the page and not when the pages get turbolinked. On turbolinking I can keep clicking the submit button and nothing happens. This only happens in production for some reason.

Removing turbolinks fixes the problem but I want the speed gains from it.

One issue I think it could be is that the modals are initially display:none; so it may be an issue that the forms are not loaded properly.

I'll test form submissions without the modals but it's a must for the application I'm making.

**deals_controller.rb**

```
def create
@deal = Deal.new(deal_params)
@deal.team = @team
@deal.user_id = current_user.id

respond_to do |format|
  if @deal.save
    format.html { redirect_to team_deals_path(@team), notice: 'Deal was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @deal }
  else
    @deals = @team.deals.all
    iwantmodal
    should_modal_be_open
    format.html { render action: 'index' }
    format.json { render json: @deal.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
end
```

I have the form located in the index action itself.

**_form.html.erb**

```
<div id="dealModal" class="modal fade">
<div class="modal-dialog">
<div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
    <h4 class="modal-title">New Deal</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <%= simple_form_for([@deal.team, @deal]) do |f| %>
      <%= f.error_notification %>

      <div class="form-inputs">
        <%= f.input :person_id do %>
          <%= f.input_field :person_id, :collection => @team.people, class: "col-lg-10" %>
          <%= link_to content_tag(:i, nil, class: 'glyphicon-plus'), new_team_person_path, type: 'button', class: 'btn btn-success col-lg-2' %>
        <% end %>
        <%= f.input :organization_id do %>
          <%= f.input_field :organization_id, :collection => @team.organizations, class: "col-lg-10" %>
          <%= link_to content_tag(:i, nil, class: 'glyphicon-plus'), new_team_organization_path, type: 'button', class: 'btn btn-success col-lg-2' %>
        <% end %>

        <%= f.input :title %>
        <%= f.input :value %>
        <%= f.input :currency_id, :include_blank => false , :collection => Currency.all,  label_method: lambda { |obj| t("#{obj.extension}") } %>

        <%= f.input :start_date, :as => :datetime_picker, input_html: {class: "deal_start_date"} %>
        <%= f.input :close_date,:as => :datetime_picker, input_html: {class: "deal_close_date"} %>

        <%= f.input :status, collection:['Pending', 'Won','Lost'], :include_blank => false %>
        <%= f.input :phone %>
        <%= f.input :visibility_id, collection: Visibility.all,:include_blank => false %>
        <%= f.input :email %>
        <%= f.input :stage_id, :collection => @team.stages, :include_blank => false %>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <div class="form-actions">
      <%= f.button :submit, class:"btn btn-primary", remote: true, method: :post %>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>

</div><!-- /.modal-content -->
</div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->



<script type="text/javascript">

if(<%= @modal %>) {
  $('#dealModal').modal('show')
}
</script>
```

The script is just used to keep the modal open in case there are validation errors in the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try installing this gem, it should help sort the jquery issues regarding turbolinks
[jquery turbolinks](https://github.com/kossnocorp/jquery.turbolinks)

Comment: The gem breaks all javascript that was alredy made to work with turbolinks and jquery, since it's going to load it twice, if that isn't an issue the gem is very nice

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the following to your form:

```
remote: true
```

And then add:

```
format.js
```

to your controller action.

This way the form will be submitted using some javascript magic. You'll need to wire up the js.erb templates too.

Comment: I'll look into this as soon as I have the time. Thanks.